# How to create a lists of checkboxFor in asp.net mvc using bootstrap class?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I want to create a list of checkboxFor, to allow aligning of new line. But i am struggling a bit, below is my logic on my View and needs some improvement.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Dietary requirement" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dietary requirements</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.None)<label for="None">None</label>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                            
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegetarian, new { @class="col-sm-2" })
                                <br/>
                                <label for="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</label>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"allow aligning of new line"*?

Comment: a list of checkbox to a new line